# Excel file saved with wrap text is opened without wraping in Libreoffice and soffice

Tags: python, excel, ms-office, openpyxl, libreoffice

I have set wrap text for the cell and auto height in Microsoft office 2007 with the new format xlsx (it works the same for the old xls).

When I save the file and when I open it with Libreoffice the wrap text doesn't work (it shows the cell on one row, while the text inside may be is wrapped - but I cannot see it). Then I go to the menu File -> Text -> and I see here Wrap text selected. I deselect it and then the column height automatically changes to height that is the height of the cell with wrapped text, but the text is on one line. Then I go to File -> Text -> Wrap text again and I select it and finally then everything looks normal.

The problem is that I need to have the column height of wrapped text recognized by Libreoffice somehow in order to have everything working right after open the xlsx file, without doing any changes on it.

So is there way to set this row height from Microsoft office in a way that is recognized by Libreoffice. For creating the Microsoft excel file I use template + openpyxl. I have set the wrap text in python over the xlsx template (using openpyxl) and in the template before.

But I think that is not openpyxl specific because using just Microsoft office, saving the xlsx file, and opening with Libreoffice is showing the cell the wrong way. 
Using the whole procedure 1.Microsoft xlsx 2.python openpyxl 3. saving the file leads to having normal Microsoft file with row height working , and having one line cell inside Libreoffice for wrapped text.
So I don't know how to solve this. There might be solution using openpyxl or using just microsoft office, but I have to have the file to open in libre office with this wrapped text (row height) working, because afterwards I send the file programmatically to soffice to export it as pdf

```
subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', path_xlsx, '--outdir', directory_xlsx])
```

and thus I don't have the option to open the file and change this manually. 
*Chanigng the pdf export solution is not an option*

==============

Before editing the wrap option from Libreoffice the row looks this way in the sheet (this code is extracted from the xlsx archive from the sheet file xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml):

```
<row r="4" spans="1:13">
```

after edit it looks like this:

```
<row r="4" customFormat="false" ht="41.95" hidden="false" customHeight="false" outlineLevel="0" collapsed="false">
```

So may be if there is a way to add collapsed="false", customHeight="false" and customFormat="false" via openpyxl this could solve the problem.

Edit 1:
I found them in the openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions module. But they cannot be set.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to set height on every row depending on the content that it has using openpyxl. This can be done if we use mono font and we calculate the possible width and height depending on the biggest cell in the row. This is not perfect solution, because there can be extra space, and it can break in some cases, so I don't accept this as answer. I have increased the constant giving more space for any case (making the height bigger), and thus this cannot be accepted answer, but still is solution.